# Eclipse Helios gives error Java was started but returned exit code -805306369

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-7-x64

[image: Eclipse errroe]

He frnds when i am using Eclipse Heios 64 bit version in Windows 7 64 bit.
I have installed JDK 64 bit. But After opening Eclipse it is not respondin. So when i close eclipse it gives above error. I can just open eclipse. I can't perform any operation in Eclipse. please give me solution for this problem.

Comment: Is your 64 bit JVM really installed in "C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe"?  Really??  'Cos that's what the Eclipse launcher is *trying* to use!

Comment: This is my Eclipse.ini file

`-startup

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m`

Comment: @StephenC javaw.exe is there in c:\windows\system32

Answer (score 1):

Add the following option in your eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
<<PATH TO YOUR 64-bit Java installation>>\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: thanx Arjun i tried this thing,but after opening Eclipse it is not responding as previous it gives error message

Comment: Error log while running Eclipse
`Error while logging event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Logging exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error while logging event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Logging exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error while logging event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Logging exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
Error while logging event loop exception:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
`

Comment: `Exception in thread "Java indexing"
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler i
n thread "Java indexing"`

Answer (score 0):

Fore me, Eclipse was hanging on "Resolving Error Markers" and was unable to start, even after an hour.  I was getting the same error message when I killed the program.

With Eclipse shutdown, I used a text editor to check out the last layout file I edited.  I found that I had several instances of **@+id**/ in my relative references. So, it looked like I was declaring the same R.id several times.  I eliminated the unneeded "+"'s and it started just fine!